# Generating one XML file from another using Python

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

How would one go about generating a local XML file from a url?
I need to be able to select out certain values from the remote XML file and place thme into a local one. Currently I only have snippets.

```
from xml.dom import minidom  
from urllib.request import urlopen  
import requests  

url = 'http://url.php'  
private_list = [16735,7456,18114]  

xmldoc = minidom.parse(urlopen(url))  
public_list = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('server')  
for public_server in public_list:
    for private_server in private_list:
        if (public_server.attributes['id'].value) == str(private_server):
          print("Found one!")
```

Sadly that is about as far as I can get I am able to grab the correct number of elements from the public list but I am not sure how to take those elements and build a local copy of those.
Can anyone assist?

Edit: Example
The example XML looks like this:

```
<settings>
  <servers>
    <server url="192.168.1.100" name="CentOS" id="12" host="Kirk.corporate.lan"/>
    <server url="10.0.0.95" name="Ubunutu" id="4" url2="192.168.1.50" host="Spock.corporate.lan"/>
    <server url="10.0.1.95" id="30" host="scotty.corporate.lan"/>
  </servers>
</settings>
```

I this example my list will only include ID 4. So I want to take just that subelement whos ID = 4. I can find that with my code above I dont know how to take that entire element though and shove it into a new file.

It looks like with xml.etree.ElementTree I can do

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
settings = ET.Element('settings')
servers = ET.SubElement(settings, 'servers')
```

That will build the base but thats about as far as I can get successfully.

Edit 2:
Got a little further

```
from lxml import etree
root = etree.Element('settings')
main = etree.SubElement(root,'servers')
main = etree.SubElement(main, "server", url = "192.168.1.100", name="CentOS", id="12", host="Kirk.corporate.lan")
```

Comment: Read [building-xml-documents](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#building-xml-documents)

Comment: share what is returned by `urlopen(url)` and how the destination XML should look like.

Comment: Would you be able to look at my edit? I am new to actually posting in stackoverflow so and edit looked like the best route for making a better explanation. Saldly I have no control over the how the XML should be structured. It does not look right to me.